# What is wrong in my code that my dropdown list isn't working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my Index Action,
I give all products to my view

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _productRepo.GetAllAsync());
}
```

This is my Create Action,
I selected all categories Id and Name to View.Categories

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,SKU,Description,Price,OldPrice,Status,IsMenuItem,Count,CategoryId")] Product productModel)
{
    ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(await _categoryrepo.GetAllAsync() , "Id" , "Name");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _productRepo.CreateAsync(productModel);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(productModel);
}
```

This is my view

```
@model OnlineShopArmenia.Models.Product

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Product</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SKU" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SKU" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SKU" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Status" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsMenuItem" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsMenuItem)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Count" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Count" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Count" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Categories :</label>
                <select name="Id" asp-for="Id" class="formcontrol" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories">
                    <option value="@ViewBag.Categories"></option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

This is Product Model

```
public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public bool IsMenuItem { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

This is Category Model

```
public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

---

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgy4O.png)

I want to see Categories in dropdown list, how can I do it ?
I think that we must change attributes in `<select>` and `<option>` tags,
Please, help me to fix it

Comment: You need to remove `<option value="@ViewBag.Categories"></option>` and change `asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"` to `asp-items="@ViewBag.Categories"`

Comment: It did not help

Comment: Is there any other `Create` Action method in your controller?

Comment: yes--------------------- public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: You need to add `ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(await _categoryrepo.GetAllAsync() , "Id" , "Name");` code in `Create()` before `return View();`

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using the wrong action method. For create operation your controller should have two action methods - a `GET` method and a `POST` method. The one you are using now (marked with `[HttpPost]`) is for receiving data from your view, once you try to save them. To pass data to the view (while you are creating it), use an action method marked with `[HttpGet]` attribute (or, not marked with any attribute at all). Following `GET` method should be sufficient to create your view -

```
[HttpGet]  // this attribute is optional
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(await _categoryrepo.GetAllAsync() , "Id" , "Name");
    return View();
}
```

2. You are marking the `select` tag wrong, it should represent the foreign key property `CategoryId`, not the `Id` of the product -

```
<select asp-for="CategoryId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"></select>
```

You don't need the `option` tag unless you want a display-value like `Please select a Category` or something -

```
<select asp-for="CategoryId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories">
    <option value="">Please choose user category:</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT :**
I'm not sure what version of ASP.NET MVC or, ASP.NET Core MVC you are using, but the razor syntax above works in `.NET 5`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `asp-items="@ViewBag.Categories"`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Not sure about the previous versions, I never worked with ASP.NET MVC, Core or non-Core.  But this works with `.Net 5`. I'll add an Edit regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

you should have 2 actions -to create or edit view and save data.

Your action to create view should be looking like this:

```
[HttpGet]  // this attribute is optional
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
  
    return  await Edit(0);
}
[HttpGet("{id?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
{
      ProductModel model=null;
if id=0 model=new Product();
else model= await _productRepo.GetAsync(id);
 ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(await _categoryrepo.GetAllAsync() 
, "Id" , "Name");

    return View(model);
}
```

and fix your select:

```
 <select name="categoryId" asp-for="CategoryId" class="formcontrol" asp-items="@ViewBag.Categories">
 </select>
```

Comment: (1). `[HttpGet]` methods does not need a `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute, (2). You don't need that `id` parameter and to fetch existing product, because its a create operation, (3) the `select` tag should represent the `CategoryId` property, not `Id`

Comment: @atiyar- Thanks for CategoryId , i just will never get  used that  some people can make so many errors  in one line of code. So I am not checking everything.  About Id - I usually use the same action for create new and edit existed one.  Just checking id  to decide if create new or edit.